# How to write a docker file when we have to get a values from a running container and make a link

Tags: magento, docker, dockerfile

Trying to run Magento2 in docker container. This is what I have done for now

1. Created a docker container running mysql
2. Created a docker container running magento2

Now I can start the docker container with magento2 and make a link to mysql container.

Then after I am accessing the mysql datas like database name and others details and running the magento commands like

```
./magento setup:config:set --db-host=172.17.0.2 --db-name=mydb --db-user=admin --db-password=password
```

> So can I write this things within the Dockerfile and create a build
>   and than only run the container . What is the exact way to do it. Is
>   it possible without making use of docker-composer.

I hope I am clear with what I want to explain

Answer (score 1):

So you want to automate the steps that you have done...

You can use docker-compose to start both containers and link them. The compose file will look something like:

```
version: '3'
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql

  magneto:
    image: ...
    links:
      - mysql
    depends_on:
      - mysql
  ...
```

You can then start both containers by running `docker-compose up`. This should give you an identical environment to the one you have created by starting each container separately.

Comment: I know the solution is docker-compose but wondering how will this get handled by it . For now I wrote this magento commands within the dockerfile `RUN cd /usr/html/bin  && \ ./magento setup:config:set --db-host=172.17.0.2 --db-name=mydb --db-user=admin --db-password=password` . How does it handle it.

Comment: @TaraPrasadGurung This means that you start the my_sql container before building the image. To handle that in docker compose you use `depend_on` property. Additionaly, you seem to be getting the ip of the mysql container (`172.17.0.2`) and putting that in the command. In compose, you don't need that, you can  use `--db-host=mysql` and the ip will be resolved. After that handling the above command should be identical to that with the `docker build` command.